# CORS GET returns an empty response body in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, backbone.js, cors

From a RESTful Backbone application, I'm doing CORS requests from `mydomain.com` to `myExtdomain.com`.

I *did* set up CORS on my `myExtdomain.com` server, I'm responding to `OPTIONS` verb (any URL) with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

Status Code: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

And to my API calls on `myExtdomain.com` with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json

Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I even desperately tried to respond to *all* my HTTP requests on `myExtdomain.com` with everything:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Type: application/json

Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

### The problem

- Everything works fine in Chrome
- In Firefox, my `PUT` requests work, but my `GET` requests "kinda fail"...

### "Kinda fail" definition

- The returned HTTP status code is `200 OK`
- But the response is empty (No Response Body/Size 0 KB).. It supposed to be some `JSON`.
- But, for some reason, every once in 100 times, one `GET` request works

### The boring details a.k.a "The Headers"

Responding to `OPTIONS` verb:

```
REQUEST HEADERS
-----------------
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Origin: http://mydomain.com
Host:   www.myExtdomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method:  PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

RESPONSE HEADERS
-----------------
X-Powered-By:   ASP.NET
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date:   Fri, 15 Nov 2013 07:01:57 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:   POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:   Content-Type
```

A `PUT` request:

```
REQUEST HEADERS
----------------
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Referer:    http://mydomain.com/account
Origin: http://mydomain.com
Host:   www.myExtdomain.com
Content-Type:   application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

RESPONSE HEADERS
----------------
X-Powered-By:   ASP.NET
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date:   Fri, 15 Nov 2013 07:01:57 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    *

BODY RESPONSE
--------------
_Some_Json_Here_
```

The *magic* `GET` request:

```
REQUEST HEADERS
----------------
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Referer:    http://mydomain.com/somepage
Origin: http://mydomain.com
Host:   www.myExtdomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

RESPONSE HEADERS
----------------
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Last-Modified:  Fri, 15 Nov 2013 06:58:18 GMT
Date:   Fri, 15 Nov 2013 07:01:57 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json
Content-Length: 4041
Connection: keep-alive

RESPONSE BODY
--------------
Empty (0KB), it's supposed to be some JSON, that *SOMETIMES* (1/100) I get.. Magic.
```

### Closing thoughts

- As you can see the Response Headers of the magic `GET` request do not even include the CORS Headers I do set on `myExtdomain.com`
- The `PUT` request on the other hand does include them..
- Again, everything works just fine in Chrome, all the Response Headers are present, I get my `JSON` as expected, etc..
- I spent a rather long time [studying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (was not enough apparently), trying to break down what's needed/not needed and not copy/pasting random code
- `JSONP` for `GET` requests is *not* an alternative for me
- All my requests (any verb) are made from non-secure pages (*not* from `https://`)
- I'm desperate..

Comment: for your get request, is content-length non-zero every time? or it's non-zero sometimes (1/100) also?

Comment: It's non-zero sometimes (1/100). So 0 KB most of the times (99/100). Basically everything is working as expected _only_ 1/100 times.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to all my API calls Responses (on `myExtdomain.com`) solved my problem:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

For some reason, Firefox was caching my API calls, and when cached, FF was not able to parse the JSON again.. Ending up in an empty response body or whatever error that was..

Now I remember this is not the first time I have to force `no-cache` with Firefox..

Again, everything was working fine with Chrome, Chrome does not need the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header.

If someone knows about this difference between FF and Chrome (default settings??), I'd be curious to know more about it.

Hope this will save some time to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in response headers of server side: this is the symmetric of setting `request.withCredentials = true;` for a `XMLHttpRequest` object on client side.

Comment: This did work surprinsingly, even though communication was via a stateless REST Protocol. CORS is really poorly designed.