# React Js Axios Post Request not receiving body back from web api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I have a web api that is set up to generate a token for to return when you send it a username and password that are the same this works through postman if you give a body like so

[image]

this works it gives you a token and the correct information but when i do it from chrome, firefox or ie it gives me an error my code is this,

```
var d = {
        username: Uname,
        surname: Pword,
        grant_type: "password",
        client_id: "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022",
    };
    console.log(d);

    var self = this;
    return (
        axios.post('http://localhost/hydraauth/oauth/token', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: d
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            self.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                Uname: Uname,
            }, function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("Login", true);
                sessionStorage.setItem("Uname", Uname)
                window.location.href = "/";
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response){
            console.log(error.response)
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else {
            window.alert("Incorrect Username Or Password Or Unauthorized To Access This.")
            }
        })
    );
```

which gives me this error in chrome

[image]

here is the error expanded

[image]

image of the network tab in chrome the response tab is empty

[image]

Comment: i guess the problem is because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @BardiaRastin How can it be cors when it works from postman

Comment: because CORS only exists in browsers ...

Comment: where is the cors error though because in my web api it is setup with cors

Comment: take a look at network tab in developer tools also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995997/cors-get-returns-an-empty-response-body-in-firefox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813645/options-http-methods-gives-an-empty-response-on-heroku)

Comment: @BardiaRastin neither of them solved my issue i added access-control-allow-origin,cache-control,content-type to my header and changed it to https and nothing happens

Comment: can you edit your post and attach screenshots from network tab ?

Comment: @BardiaRastin added a screenshot

Comment: the problem is because of the server returning empty response for requests with OPTIONS method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios has an issue with sending data via body so you need to use [npm plugin query string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

and use it like so

```
axios.post("http://localhost/hydraauth/oauth/token", querystring.stringify({ "username": Uname, "password": Pword, "grant_type": "password", "client_id": "eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJTYXZ2eS1Dcm0tUmVhY3QtSnMtU3lzdGVtIn0" }))
```