# OPTIONS net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE Angular - What are the CORS settings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

I am trying to make a get request to a mongoDB which is on a server. This is the same server that my webpage will be hosted. I have created an API so that the webpage can make requests to the mongoDB.

My first issue was with it being blocked by CORS policy so I looked into this and the information I found led to me adding in `corsOptions` to `server.js` (the API file running on the server).

This is my `server.js` (The API file I am running on the server to connect the webpage with `node.js` connect to the mongoDB):

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();


const corsOptions = {
    origin = true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
    maxAge: 600,
};
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions))
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://serverip:27017/database');

// Express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));

// Start server
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

My `.component.ts` runs a simple `httpClient.get` request to get the information, like so:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
};

this.httpService.get('http://serverip:3000/api/collection/', httpOptions).subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error => {
        console.log('Error occured', error);
    }
)
```

I get the following error in Google Chrome:

```
OPTIONS http://serverip:3000/api/collection/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've run Chrome with this command in `WIN`+`R`:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

I get this error on that Chrome:

```
OPTIONS http://serverip:3000/api/collection/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I remove the code in the `server.js` that is to do with CORS, and load the webpage in the Chrome with no web security then webpage loads the data from MongoDB with no issues at all.

I also tried to put `OPTIONS` into the `methods` in the `server.js` but I still get the same error.

I assume this error is from the `corsOptions` but what do i need to change/add to resolve this error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The error suggest an empty response from the server. What do you expect from the server? you are no returning anything.

Comment: @MMSA I am expecting a JSON format response, when using Chrome with security disabled I get this. The mongoDB is not blank so it should be returning this.

Comment: Did you try to replace the serverIP with localhost in both?

Comment: @MMSA I get the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
` when changing it all to localhost.

Comment: Did you try ”http://serverip:3000/api/collection/” in your browser?

Comment: Just for testing you might also try in your terminal (if you are using Mac) : `curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/collection`

Comment: @MMSA If remove `corsOptions` and `app.use()` from `server.js` then I get the expected result, this works in both browsers.

Comment: I’m guessing the specific problem is `preflightContinue: true`. I don’t know what that does but I suspect you don’t want to be setting it.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I removed `preflightContinue: true` and I still get the same error. I got all of that information from a question that appeared to have a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to test yout API using Postman to ensure you have the correct response. secondly try to add cors withou any option. this ensures you to use default cors options, and then try to add your's one by one.

`app.use(cors())`

lastly, you do not need to add any headr to your http call, so you can remove this part

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
};
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help! I thought that the lack of header was what was causing my initial CORS error. Clearly not!

Comment: Actually this header is added to the http call by the browser, so normally we don't need to overwrite that.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing if you added

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

as header to the client call, that should do the trick.

Reference: "[CORS GET returns an empty response body in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995997/cors-get-returns-an-empty-response-body-in-firefox)"

Comment: My apologies! I forgot to include my headers in the question! I will update my question now, I already had the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a header but did not have the other two. I added the other two and I still have the same error