# Reading data from json string to c# object

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I am developing an Angular App with .net server and the backend is written in c#. I have formed an object by combining the data from two different forms and converted object to json string using JSON.stringify. How can i convert this json string from angular to a c# object and the object should get the values from the json string.

Please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

I used this [conversion](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert json string to c# class.
**UPDATE:**
Update with controller, signalrhub and cors policy.

json object

```
const Root = {
    "Unit" : "mm",
    "test": [{
      "Val": this.Val1.isChecked,
      'Val1' : this.val2.isChecked,
    }],
    "test1" :{
      "sub":[{
        'val2' : this.valFormGroup.get('val2').value,
        'Val3' : this.valFormGroup.get('val3').value,
        }]
        },
}
const foo = JSON.stringify(Root);
console.log(foo);
```

json string.

```
{"Units":"mm","test":[{"Val":true,"Val1":false}], "test1":[{"Val2":"red","Val3":"5"}]}
```

c# class

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Val { get; set; }
    public bool Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class Test1
{
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
    public string Val3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public List<Test> test { get; set; }
    public List<Test1> test1 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace angular.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DIMController : Controller
    {

             private IHubContext<DIMHub> _hubContext;
        public DIMController(IHubContext<DIMHub> hubContext)
    {
  _hubContext = hubContext;
}
[HttpPost]

 public JsonResult Postdata(string json)
{
 // Your data variable is of type RootObject
 var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

 //Get your variables here as shown in first example. Something like:
 var unit=data.Units; 
 return Json(true);
}
```

SignalR hub

```
namespace angular.HubConfig
{
public class DIMHub: Hub
{
 public async Task Send1 ( string message1, Root data)
{
  await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send1", message1);
}

}
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddCors(options =>{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    builder => builder
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .AllowAnyOrigin());
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
});
```

Client

```
form(){
 var json = Root;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,  
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://localhost:5001/api/DIM/Postdata',     
    data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},  
   // contentType: "application/json",    

  // headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function (data) {
    console.log('error in sending data...:(')
  },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you setup an ASP .NET CORE Webapi it more or less does it for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
Checkout section: Add a Create method

Answer (score 2):

Your model classes are correct in accordance to your `JSON` string that you have posted in the question. All you would require is to deserialize the string correctly. I am posting a code snippet specifically for your `JSON` string. I am using the [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library which is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET.

A working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s2OXhT

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{'Units':'mm','test':[{'Val':true,'Val1':false}], 'test1':[{'Val2':'red','Val3':'5'}]}";
        var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Units);

        foreach(var values in data.test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values.Val);  
            Console.WriteLine(values.Val1);
        }

        foreach(var values1 in data.test1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values1.Val2);    
            Console.WriteLine(values1.Val3);
        }       
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public bool Val { get; set; }
    public bool Val1 { get; set; }
}

public class Test1
{
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
    public string Val3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public List<Test> test { get; set; }
    public List<Test1> test1 { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
mm
True
False
red
5
```

**Update:** 
In the above part, I have given you an example of how to deserialize your `JSON` string correctly. In the example below, I am giving a very basic example of how you can use `AJAX` to post your values as a `JSON` string to your `Controller` method. I am not very familiar with Angular so I will try my best here:

Your `AJAX` call would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const Root = {
    "Unit" : "mm",
    "test": [{
      "Val": this.Val1.isChecked,
      'Val1' : this.val2.isChecked,
    }],
    "test1" :{
      "sub":[{
        'val2' : this.valFormGroup.get('val2').value,
        'Val3' : this.valFormGroup.get('val3').value,
        }]
        },
     }

var json = Root;

//Assuming a button click event here but you can use any event 
$('#myBtn').click(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessJSON", "Home")', // This can be a WEB API method or a Controller method. You can even call 3rd party WEB API  
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(data)
         },
         error: function (data) {
           console.log('error in sending data...:(')
         },
    });
};
</script>
```

Your `Controller` would look like something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProcessJSON(string json)
{
 // Your data variable is of type RootObject
 var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

 //Get your variables here as shown in first example. Something like:
 var unit=data.Units; //mm

 return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest how can i import the jsonsting from angular client to c# object. my jsonstring is in appcomponent.ts.

Comment: @ramkris For that you would need to setup your a web method that will process this JSON string as a payload. You can use AJAX to send your json string via your angular client.

Comment: Thanks for your time Rahul. I will check it out.

Comment: @ramkris I will update my answer with a very basic example of how you can achieve this.

Comment: I did not try it at. I am working on other issue. I will update as soon as i try the solution. Thank you very much for asking.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I have tried your solution but i am getting an error "OPTIONS localhost:5001/api/Ds1/ProcessJSON net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE zone.js:3331". can you please guide me regarding this.

Comment: @ramkris Not quite sure but it could be a `CORS` issue. Can you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833785/options-neterr-empty-response-angular-what-are-the-cors-settings

Comment: Thanks for asking, No luck. I tried using different Cors policies. I am trying to send data using SignalR instead of ajax and http post methods.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding what i have appled. can you please check it. Thanks.

Comment: @ramkris Since you are using SignalR, in your `CORS` setup, remove: `.AllowCredentials()` and add `.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true)` or `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001")`

Comment: I am getting new errors when i tried your suggestion.                                                         Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/message/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:58968' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: @ramkris Did you try setting your CORS like: `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:58968")`?

Comment: @ramkris Please take a look at this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5385

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
jsonString = {"Units":"mm","test":[{"Val":true,"Val1":false}], "test1":[{"Val2":"red","Val3":"5"}]}

var data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ASP.NET Web Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) Project

You used Root>test1 in "sub" property.

**Javascript**

```
    var Root = {
        "Unit" : "mm",
        "test": [{
          "Val": this.Val1.isChecked,
          'Val1' : this.val2.isChecked,
        }],
        "test1" :{
          "sub":[{
            'val2' : this.valFormGroup.get('val2').value,
            'Val3' : this.valFormGroup.get('val3').value,
            }]
            },
    }

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://YouSite/api/controller/YouActionName',        
        data: Root ,
        dataType: "json",
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        success: function (data) {
           console.log("Message: ",data.Message);
           console.log("Status: ", data.MyStatus);
         },
         error: function (data) {
           console.warn(data);
         },
    });
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Message:  transaction successful
Status:  true
```

**ASP.NET Web Api Controller**

ASP.NET WebApi automatically serializes json data

```
[HttpPost]
public MyResponseModel YouActionName([FromBody]MyRootObject data)
{
 var unit=data.Unit;
 var test=data.test;
 var subs=data.test1.sub;
var response = new MyResponseModel(){ Message="transaction successful", MyStatus=true};
//you can customize your return object
 return response;
}
```

**Web Api Route**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
        }
    }
```

**Request Models**

```
  public class Test
    {
        public bool Val { get; set; }
        public bool Val1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test1
    {
        public List<Sub> sub { get; set; }
    }
    public class Sub
    {
        public string Val2 { get; set; }
        public string Val3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Units { get; set; }
        public List<Test> test { get; set; }
        public List<Test1> test1 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Response Model**

```
 public class MyResponseModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool MyStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Faith, I have tried your solution but i am getting an error "OPTIONS http://localhost:5001/api/Ds/post net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE  zone.js:3331". can you please guide me regarding this.

Comment: @ramkris need to see the codes. This error is not related to my solution. May be the address you requested or a setting you missed. Upload your entire project to github and let's check it out.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
var obj=JSON.parse("yourjsonstring")

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked, does not provide any explanation of the code being suggested, and the code is incorrect in the first place. When answering a question make sure you have fully read the question before providing an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31213065)